# Search into linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

```
struct Players
{
    int pid;                      /*Player's identifier*/
    int is_alien;                 /*Alien flag*/
    int evidence;                 /*Amount of evidence*/
    struct Players *prev;         /*Pointer to the previous node*/
    struct Players *next;         /*Pointer to the next node*/
    struct Tasks *tasks_head;     /*Pointer to the head of player's task list*/
    struct Tasks *tasks_sentinel; /*Pointer to the sentinel of player's task list*/
};

/**
 * Structure defining a node of the airplane linked list
 */
struct Tasks
{
    int tid;                      /*Task's identifier*/
    int difficulty;               /*Task's difficulty*/
    struct Tasks *next;           /*Pointer to the next node*/  
};
struct Player *players_head; //Global pointer
```

So Im having these. I need to search for a player's Task.
I have made

```
struct Players *player=players_head;
struct Tasks *tasks,*test;
test=(struct Tasks*)malloc(sizeof(struct Tasks));

if(player == NULL) {
    return 0;
}

while(player != NULL) {
    test=player->tasks_head;
    //some other code..
```

My problem is why `test=player->task_head`  is null. the problem is at `player->tasks_head`
i have also tried  with  obj `tasks = player->tasks_head`any help? Thanks

Comment: [mcve] will go a long way toward providing what is needed for someone to help you.

Comment: You set `player` to be equal to `players_head`. Why do you not expect `players_head` to be null?

Comment: You are assiging to `struct Players* player` a pointer to `Player` struct. Is this intentional?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you have never set the tasks_head pointer to point to the list's head, have you?

It should be done first time in the list constructor and every time you add an item to the head of the list it should be changed to the updated one.

Hope it helped!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialized `players_head` in your code. There must be a place in your `main` (or some other function) that you must type:

```
    players_head = malloc(sizeof(struct Player));
```

and then initialize the pointer to some player.

Also, you can type:

```
typedef struct Players
{
    ...
    your code
    ...
} player;
```

so that you can instance player objects without having to type "struct" before (it renames struct Player to player).

Comment: when i print  %s (void *)  players_head i get  0x8983170 so its not nill..  i also do malloc like u said but nothing ...